# PLSQL - How to find Monday and Friday of the week of a given date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, dayofweek, weekday

I have spent days trying to figure this out to no avail, so hopefully someone can help me. I have a queried date set which contains several fields including a column of dates. What I want to do is create a new field in my query that tells what the Monday and Friday is for the week of that row's particular date.

So for example; if the date in one of my rows is "1/16/18", 
the new field should indicate "1/15/18 - 1/19/18".

So basically I need to be able to extract the Monday date (1/15/18) and the Friday date (1/19/18) of the week of 1/16/18 and then concatenate the two with a dash ( - ) in between. I need to do this for every row.

How on earth do I do this? I've been struggling just to figure out how to find the Monday or Friday of the given date...

Comment: Please show sample data in a table format.

Comment: The only ambiguity is the definition of "week" (and even then, there is an ambiguity only if the input date is a Saturday or a Sunday). Namely: is a week from Monday to Sunday? Then for a Sunday, the Monday of the same week precedes the input (the Sunday). But if a week starts on Sunday and ends the following Saturday, then "the Monday of the week of a Sunday" starts on the Monday **following** the Sunday. Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your column is of type `date`, you can use [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8) to get the first day of the week (monday) and then add 4 days to get the friday.

For example:

```
with yourTable(d) as (select sysdate from dual)
select trunc(d, 'iw'), trunc(d, 'iw') + 4
from yourTable
```

To format the date as a string in the needed format, you can use [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html); for example:

```
with yourTable(d) as (select sysdate from dual)
select to_char(trunc(d, 'iw'), 'dd/mm/yy') ||'-'|| to_char(trunc(d, 'iw') + 4, 'dd/mm/yy')
from yourTable
```

gives

```
15/01/2018-19/01/18
```

Comment: Aren't weeks Sunday - Saturday in SQL?

Comment: Looks like it's Oracle due to the "PLSQL" in the title, though admittedly that could mean anything. In which case `'IW'` means [the first day of the calendar week as defined by the ISO 8601 standard, which is Monday](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html) (quoting from Oracle 12.2 docs).

Comment: Yes, I am coding in Oracle.

Comment: So I took your suggestion and concatenated it, and this appears to work: , CONCAT(CONCAT(TRUNC(CALL_DATE, 'iw'),' - '),TRUNC(CALL_DATE, 'iw') + 4) as "Week Dates"

Comment: But how do I get the format to be "MM/DD/YY"? Right now my result is looking like "01-JAN-18 - 05-JAN-18"

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler, canonical Oracle method to this but you can still reduce it to a simple calculation on your own either way. I'm going to assume you're dealing with only dates falling Monday through Friday. If you do need to deal with weekend dates then you might have to be more explicit about which logical week they should be attached to.

```
<date> - (to_char(<date>, 'D') - 2) -- Monday
<date> + (6 - to_char(<date>, 'D')) -- Friday
```

In principle all you need to do is add/subtract the appropriate number of days based on the current day of week (from 1 - 7). There are some implicit casts going on in there and it would probably be wise to handle those better. You might also want to check into NLS settings to make sure you can rely on `to_char()` using Sunday as the first day of week.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `NEXT_DAY` function, as in:

```
SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'MON')) - INTERVAL '7' DAY AS PREV_MONDAY,
       TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'FRI'))                    AS NEXT_FRIDAY
  FROM DUAL;
```

Note that using the above, on weekends the Monday will be the Monday preceding the current date, and the Friday will be the Friday following the current date, i.e. there will be 11 days between the two days.

You can also use

```
SELECT TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'MON')) - INTERVAL '7' DAY AS PREV_MONDAY,
       TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'MON')) - INTERVAL '3' DAY AS NEXT_FRIDAY
  FROM DUAL;
```

in which case the Monday and Friday will always be from the same week, but if SYSDATE is on a weekend the Monday and Friday returned will be from the PREVIOUS week.